# Laravel 5.8 API + WordPress integration

Tags: wordpress, laravel, api, postman

I am building an APP with Laravel and all functions from User model must provide through API and show them in WP.

They need to "connect with MyApp(login)" and use the same credentials like in Laravel. I made login API and it returns token, expiration date, but when I need to access user object and return it, it says `"message": "Unauthenticated."`

This is my code:

**LOGIN**

```
  public function login(Request $request){
      $request->validate([
          'email' => 'required|string|email',
          'password' => 'required|string',
      ]);

      $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

      if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
          return response()->json([
              'message' => 'Unauthorized'
          ], 401);
      }
      $user = $request->user();

      $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token ' . str_random(10));

      $token = $tokenResult->token;

      if ($request->remember_me) {
          $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(10);
      }

      $token->save();

      return response()->json([
          'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
          'token_type' => 'Bearer',
          'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
              $tokenResult->token->expires_at)
              ->toDateTimeString(),
      ]);
  }
```

**Auth.php**

```
    'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ]
],
```

**Api.php**

```
  Route::post('/login', 'Api\AuthController@login')->name('login.api');
  Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request){return $request->user();});
  // Route::post('/register', 'Api\AuthController@register')->name('register.api');

  Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
     Route::get('/logout', 'Api\AuthController@logout')->name('logout');
  });
```

**Also i have this in both .htaccess**

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I need to fetch user object and retrieve informations by calling model function ex. ***$user->allClients***.

Comment: Please have a look at: https://laraveldaily.com/using-wordpress-rest-api-laravel
It may help you.

Comment: Another one in more details: https://laravel-news.com/wordpress-api-with-laravel

Comment: @sssurii I need it from Laravel to WordPress.